# Fedora 31 and openvswitch bridge with network-manager...no way?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, bridge

Fedora-31 consider the network-scripts package deprecated(is already possible to install it but they warn you to migrate to network-manager).
So I use Network-Manager(of course the ovs plugin is installed)
first I create the bridge on openvswitch and add enp1s0 as port

```
ovs-vsctl add-br bridge0
ovs-vsctl add-port bridge0 enp1s0
```

then I run those commands

```
nmcli connection add type ovs-bridge conn.interface-name bridge0 ipv4.method auto
nmcli connection add type ovs-port connection.interface-name port0 master bridge0
nmcli connection add type ovs-interface slave-type ovs-port connection.interface-name enp1s0 master port0
```

I want a bridge0 with one port(enp1s0) with dynamic address.
With the classical linux bridge is easy.
After reboot..no ip on bridge0!
I try also this way

```
dhclient -v bridge0
```

but go to timeout.
I have tried with selinux and firewall disabled, no way.
Nmcli report this

```
enp1s0              7d27e505-7931-4838-bea1-08c9fbf759ae  ethernet       enp1s0  
virbr0              0fc3c827-9649-4ef6-a96e-31a24228f7d9  bridge         virbr0  
ovs-bridge-bridge0  12abce0d-488a-444e-99b3-390cbb4edebd  ovs-bridge     bridge0 
ovs-slave-port0     247757ec-76e0-425c-8484-311b48e4de01  ovs-port       port0
```

all is green except for the connection ovs-slave-port0

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use NetworkManager, you don't need to add the bridge/port with `ovs-vsctl`. Possibly it's even preventing NM from actually taking over the externally created OVS devices (hence not only being unnecessary but harmful).

Also, you would not directly run `dhclient` on a device managed by NetworkManager. I mean, for some ad hoc testing you may do that, but in general that is interfering with NetworkManager.

Also, as explained in `man nm-openswitch`, there is a difference between `ovs-vsctl` and NetworkManager. Quote:

> - The configuration is made up of Bridges, Ports and Interfaces. Interfaces are always enslaved to Ports, and Ports are always enslaved to Bridges.
> - NetworkManager only creates Bridges, Ports and Interfaces you ask it to. Unlike ovs-vsctl, it doesn't create the local interface nor its port automatically.

In other words, while `ovs-vsctl add-br` also creates an interface for you, with NetworkManager you have to explicitly activate a profile for that. That's why `dhclient bridge0` doesn't work, because no such interface exists (and you shouldn't run `dhclient` explicitly).

In other words: in `nmcli device` you see an `ovs-bridge` and an `ovs-port`. But these devices are entirely inside OVS (`ovs-vsctl show`). You won't see them in `ip link` and you can't configure IP addresses on them. Kernel doesn't know about these interfaces. You need to enslave a "real" interface to the `ovs-port` and on that you (or NetworkManager) can configure IP addresses.

You can do two things here:

- Either enslave an Ethernet device

  ```
  nmcli con add type ethernet slave-type ovs-port master port0 interface-name enp1s0 ...
  ```
- or create an ovs-interface

  ```
  nmcli con add type ovs-interface slave-type ovs-port master port0 interface-name bridge0-if0 ...
  ```

On such interfaces you can configure IP addresses, by specifing the IP configuration in the respective profiles.

And as always, be aware of the difference between a NetworkManager connection profile and a device. In NetworkManager, you configure (and create) devices by activating suitable profiles.

I wrote the examples from memory to give you an idea. I suggest you instead read `man nm-openvswitch` and follow the examples there. Good luck.